# Unable to call native all iOS functions from UIWebView using JavaScriptCore and JSContext

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Let me explain my question it is bugging me from long time. Any help will be appreciated. Please help.

I am working on hybrid kind of app in iOS. I am using `UIWebView` for loading webpages from http://myserver.com (its example its not actual URL) I have hosted multiple webpages on this server.

I am using **"JSContext"** to communicate between **javascript** (webpages loaded from my server) in `UIWebView` and native iOS functions.

I have followed procedure given at [UIWebView JavaScript losing reference to iOS JSContext namespace (object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714365/uiwebview-javascript-losing-reference-to-ios-jscontext-namespace-object.here) the context was getting lost but I have added workaround provided in solution of this question.
Event then for some frame load inside `UIWebView` my iOS context is getting vanished.
After following following steps context gets vanished.

1. I load **page1** from myserver in `UIWebView`. Almost all works well all functions OS native iOS are called from **javascript**.
2. Now when second page2 is loaded as result of interaction in **page1**, in same `UIWebView` **javascript** context gets vanished.

There is one more magical thing. if I have directly load page2 in `UIWebView` instead of indirect loading (**page1**->**page2**). All works well all native methods are called from `UIwebView` as expected.
Please help. If you want more info please ask.

Comment: Is it duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714365/uiwebview-javascript-losing-reference-to-ios-jscontext-namespace-object ?

Comment: This is the same thing happening on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714365/uiwebview-javascript-losing-reference-to-ios-jscontext-namespace-object. When a new page is loaded, the new page gets a new JSContext. You mentioned a frame load. Does the frame have the JSContext set correctly?

Comment: When some part of page loads without calling webViewDidFinishedloading. I can not set JSContext for such request.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, stealing and using the UIWebView's JavaScriptContext in this way is likely a path to app rejection.

But if this is just a science project...

You might try another technique for obtaining the JavaScriptContext.  I present a solution in this GitHub project:

https://github.com/TomSwift/UIWebView-TS_JavaScriptContext

Basically I'm using some knowledge of how WebKit works to implement a category on NSObject to intercept some non-handeled WebKit delegate methods which are called whenever a new JavaScriptContext is created for a frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but - `(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didCreateJavaScriptContext:(JSContext *)ctx
{
   
    ctx[@"myinterface"] = self; or ctx[@"window.myinterface"] = self;
}`
And my html calling `window.myinterface.mynativefunc('hello');` not getting called at all.Please help.

Comment: example app worked but still having issue as specified by jnix.

Comment: When some part of page loads without calling webViewDidFinishedloading. I can not set JSContext for such request.

Comment: @TomSwift do you know solution ? I am still facing same problem .please help.

Comment: Sorry; without some more information it's pretty difficult to guess what's going on.  If it works in the example app then you need to figure out what's different in your code.

Comment: window is global object dowcument object build inside webpage when page gets loaded in browser/webview so I was able to call ios methods as window.iosInteface.mymethod(); to set JSContext i have used method described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714365/uiwebview-javascript-losing-reference-to-ios-jscontext-namespace-object.here. So when use same call in your example It never gets called. do you get me ?

Comment: @TomSwift bounty was expiring so i have assigned it to you, but still I did not got the solution. please suggest me a solution